# Error Undefined property: stdClass while trying to parse json file in php

Tags: php, json

I am trying to parse a json file and show its content in table using php, but for some reason I am getting (Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$managed_status in z.json)

so here is my a full example of what I have in my json file (z.json):

```
{
    "metadata": {
        "total_record_count": "1"
    },
    "devices": [
        {
            "managed_status": "2",
            "device_id": "63225421111",
            "is_supervised": true,
            "os_version": "10",
            "is_lost_mode_enabled": false,
            "serial_number": "77898789",
            "device_type": "1",
            "owned_by": "1",
            "is_removed": "false",
            "product_name": "TC26",
            "device_name": "mail@mail.com",
            "platform_type": "android",
            "located_time": "1623936014747",
            "imei": [
                "352714110033545"
            ],
            "model": "TC26",
            "customer_name": "Customer1",
            "customer_id": "10489000000041017",
            "udid": "95bd2e6ca8654910",
            "last_contact_time": "1624254859593",
            "platform_type_id": "2",
            "user": {
                "user_email": "mail@mail.com",
                "user_id": "556654548",
                "user_name": "mail@mail.com"
            },
            "device_capacity": "17.34"
        }
    ],
    "delta-token": "aHR0cHM6Ly9tZG0ubWFuYWdlZW5naW5lLmV1L2FwaS92MS9kZXZpY2VzOjoxNjI0MjU1NzA2NDI4"
}
```

and here is my php script:

```
<?php
  $json=file_get_contents('z.json');
  $data=json_decode($json);

?>

<table>

    

      <tr>
        <td>managed_status</td>
        <td>device_id</td>
        <td>is_supervised</td>
        <td>os_version</td>
      </tr>
    
    
    
      <?php foreach($data as $key=>$item): ?>
        
        <tr>
          <td><?PHP echo $item->managed_status ; ?></td>
          <td><?PHP echo $item->device_id; ?></td>
          <td><?PHP echo $item->is_supervised; ?></td>
          <td><?PHP echo $item->os_version; ?></td>

        </tr>
        
      <?php endforeach; ?>

  </table>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the foreach condition you are trying to iterate over the date, you need to replace that with $data->devices.

```
<?php

$json = file_get_contents('z.json');
$data = json_decode($json);

?>
```

```
<tr>
    <td>managed_status</td>
    <td>device_id</td>
    <td>is_supervised</td>
    <td>os_version</td>
</tr>

<?php foreach($data->devices as $key => $item): ?>

    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $item->managed_status ; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $item->device_id; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $item->is_supervised; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $item->os_version; ?></td>
    </tr>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: What a stupid mistake I've made .... Thanks a lot bro, I am reading the code since 2 hours but I've never tried to check this..... THANKS A LOT REALLY